# Clang fails with "function with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined", while GCC works

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++23

The following compiles with GCC, but not with Clang:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

constexpr auto makeNumberGenerator = [](this auto maker, int startingValue)
{
    return [maker, startingValue]<typename Generator>(this Generator generator) -> std::tuple<int, Generator>
    {
        return std::make_tuple(startingValue, maker(startingValue + 1));
    };
};

auto test = []{
    std::array<int, 5> arr;
    
    auto fn = [](this auto self, int* output, const int* end, auto callable) -> void
    {
        auto [value, newCallable] = callable();
        if (output != end)
        {
            *output = value;
            self(output + 1, end, newCallable);
        }
    };
    
    fn(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), makeNumberGenerator(0));

    return arr;
}();
```

On compiler explorer: [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/c6jco49qr), [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/Mxovx781q). Flags used: `-O2 -std=c++23`.

Outputs:

GCC:

```
test:
        .long   0
        .long   1
        .long   2
        .long   3
        .long   4
```

Clang:

```
<source>:9:47: error: function 'operator()<(lambda at <source>:5:38)>' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
    9 |         return std::make_tuple(startingValue, maker(startingValue + 1));
      |                                               ^
<source>:8:5: note: while substituting into a lambda expression here
    8 |     {
      |     ^
<source>:26:59: note: in instantiation of function template specialization '(anonymous class)::operator()<(lambda at <source>:5:38)>' requested here
   26 |     fn(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), makeNumberGenerator(0));
      |                                                           ^
<source>:5:38: note: 'operator()<(lambda at <source>:5:38)>' declared here
    5 | constexpr auto makeNumberGenerator = [](this auto maker, int startingValue)
      |                                      ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Which compiler is correct? Should this code compile according to the C++23 standard?

---

EDIT: This works on both:

```cpp
constexpr auto makeNumberGenerator = [](this auto self, int startingValue)
{
    return std::bind([startingValue](auto maker)
    {
        return std::make_tuple(startingValue, maker(startingValue + 1));
    }, self);
};
```

Changing `std::bind` to a simple lambda gives the same error as before.

---

EDIT2: Apparently, this problem is unrelated to deducing this, as this code presents the exact same issue (compiles on GCC, not on Clang):

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

constexpr auto makeNumberGenerator = [](auto maker, int startingValue)
{
    return [maker, startingValue]<typename Generator>(Generator generator) -> std::tuple<int, Generator>
    {
        return std::make_tuple(startingValue, maker(maker, startingValue + 1));
    };
};

auto test = []{
    std::array<int, 5> arr;
    
    auto fn = [](auto self, int* output, const int* end, auto callable) -> void
    {
        auto [value, newCallable] = callable(callable);
        if (output != end)
        {
            *output = value;
            self(self, output + 1, end, newCallable);
        }
    };
    
    fn(fn, std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), makeNumberGenerator(makeNumberGenerator, 0));

    return arr;
}();
```

Comment: Please tell us *how* you build? What is the exact flags and options you use? And please tell us in the question itself, making it self-contained.

Comment: Is the problem because clang hasn't finished fully implementing *deducing this* yet?

Comment: @Eljay I don't think so. According to [the official status page](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html), Clang has implemented [P0847R7](https://wg21.link/P0847R7), but not [P2797R0](https://wg21.link/P2797R0), which seems unrelated in this case.